# Magento 2 UTF-8 URL Rewrites

Tags: url-rewrite, internationalization

When will Magento 2 support utf-8 characters in URL rewrites for categories, cms and product pages? It will improve SEO by a thousand miles.

I really want to use Cyrillic letters in my URLs.

Is there a **working** module? Because I couldn't find any that are up to date..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to look [Studioraz's magento2-unicode-url](https://github.com/studioraz/magento2-unicode-url) extension, works well on my test server,